# Rendering with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a sample app using reactjs. I am very new in reactjs. I set up all the things for reactjs like 
1) Babel
2)Webpack

Using webpack I am genrating a file code.js which is included in the index file where all the code runs.

I am creating my first page but i got error like:

```
ERROR in ./components/Login/Login.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/xampp/htdocs/reactApp/components/Login/Logi
n.js: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img> (18:33)
```

I dont know why the html rendering gives me error. 
My code is like:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
export default class Home extends Component {

      render () {
    return (
      <div class="page-content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="content-wrap">
                            <h6>Sign In</h6>
                            <div class="social">
                                <a class="face_login" href="#">
                                    <span class="face_icon">
                                        <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="fb">
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="text">Sign in with Facebook</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="division">
                                    <hr class="left">
                                    <span>or</span>
                                    <hr class="right">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address">
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <div class="action">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary signup" href="index.html">Login</a>
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="already">
                        <p>Dont have an account yet?</p>
                        <a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Just read error. `img` not closed, use `<img />`

Comment: <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="fb" />

Comment: this is also saying that input tag is not closed???

Comment: @Karan well, what you gonna do?

Comment: @Karan - it has been named JSX for a reason. It is XML like syntax, so make sure it has closing tags even if it is an empty HTML element like br or img.

Comment: thanks  @ Cheezy Code

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one more problem: You used class= instead of className= everywhere. Obviously you did try to copy & paste html code. There is a great online converter which i use. It allows you to do that without errors: http://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
export default class Home extends Component {

render () {
    return (
        <div className="page-content container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div className="login-wrapper">
                        <div className="box">
                            <div className="content-wrap">
                                <h6>Sign In</h6>
                                <div className="social">
                                    <a className="face_login" href="#">
                  <span className="face_icon">
                    <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="fb" />
                  </span>
                                        <span className="text">Sign in with Facebook</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <div className="division">
                                        <hr className="left" />
                                        <span>or</span>
                                        <hr className="right" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" />
                                <input className="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                <div className="action">
                                    <a className="btn btn-primary signup" href="index.html">Login</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="already">
                            <p>Dont have an account yet?</p>
                            <a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
}
```

Hope you found this useful.

Comment: This is not always the problem if you are correctly configuring you webpack with the appropriate presets

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Oh, I did not know that kind of configuration :)
Anyways i found out that in fact `class` was available in the past, but the react team decided to stop using `class` and `for` in favour of `className ` and `htmlFor`:
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/328
I think it is reasonable to avoid that notation from now on

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly mentions what needs to be done. In JSX you need to close the singleton tags like `<br>` , `<img>` and `<input>`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
export default class Home extends Component {

      render () {
    return (
      <div class="page-content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="content-wrap">
                            <h6>Sign In</h6>
                            <div class="social">
                                <a class="face_login" href="#">
                                    <span class="face_icon">
                                        <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="fb" />
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="text">Sign in with Facebook</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="division">
                                    <hr class="left">
                                    <span>or</span>
                                    <hr class="right">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                            <div class="action">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary signup" href="index.html">Login</a>
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="already">
                        <p>Dont have an account yet?</p>
                        <a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```